# is it possible to create custom Core Image Filters ios 9?

Tags: ios, ciimage

We can create custom kernels with CIKernel language for mac. I wonder can we do the same for ios 9?

Comment: Yes, we can. Did you even consult the documentation to find out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would have been trivially answered by just looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the CIKernel documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIKernel_Class/):

> Available in iOS 8.0 and later